# Jinja2 reuse templates for new and edit

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm developing a website on appengine using Jinja2 for templating. 
I would like to use the same template for creating a new object as well as for editing an existing object.

There would be a form where the values will be populated if it was an edit or be blank if it was new. In edit mode I suppose there would be a hidden item id to load the item and change the values.

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Thanks for your help.

Karim

Comment: Do you know that Jinja templates have if-then-else tags?  Not sure what you are asking here..

Comment: In any case this sounds like a job for the forms framework, not the template.

Comment: Thank you both. I am aware of the if-then-else tags and know how to do this in the form, but basically I'm creating two forms. One for new and one for edit in the same template file. This seems inelegant to me.

Comment: Then use two templates or use the "extends" functionality.